# r - in Shiny, read excel file and plot it in GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am new to Shiny and I am working on a project that will load Excel data and plot it in GGPLOT. I have been looking at past questions/answers on Stackoverflow for a while and I'm not sure what the problem is. Do I need reactivity for this? I have pasted below what I have already accomplished. The Excel data that I would be uploading would always be in the same format (same headers) but just different data (i.e. I would like to always look at the same three headers: "number", "update_date", and "media-type).

```
###UI
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Visualizing Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                accept = c(".xlsx")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('plot1'))
  )
))

###Server
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if(is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    df<-read_excel(inFile$datapath)
    ggplot(data=df,aes(x=`Update date`,y=number,colour=`Media 
Type`))+geom_line(stat="identity")+ggtitle("Comparison")
  })
}
)
```

Comment: You did not mention what your errors were. But, the code is OK with few minor mistakes. I copied your code and ran it to fix the errors.

Comment: wrap the ui in ui and server in server variable and use `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)` to run. Also, the `Meida Type` has a new line in between. Take that out. I don't see any mistake, unless you have an issue with the plot